# Renaming "Acronyms" (glossaries package)

Tags: glossaries, naming

I'd like to rename the "Acronyms" section produced by the `glossaries` package because not all the terms I have included in it are actually acronyms but rather abbreviations.

The only way to change the name I have found so far is using `babel` to translate the name to another language. Is there a way to simply redefine the name and keep my document language?

Comment: You can set the title in the optional argument of `\printglossary` e.g. `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={Abbreviations}]`

Comment: @NicolaTalbot what about `\renewcommand*\acronymname{Abbreviations}`?

Comment: @cgnieder That can also work but `babel` may reset it if the language switches. There's more detail in [Changing the Fixed Names](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:fixednames)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Sure `babel` may change it. The question isn't very specific but unless I'm mistaken it reads like the OP doesn't (want to) use `babel`...

Comment: (FYI [Difference between an acronym and abbreviation?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3755/17712))

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're not using `babel` or `translator` or `polyglossia` then either my suggestion or @cgnieder's will work. (It would help if you could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) when you ask a question.)

First option (see [Displaying a Glossary](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:printglossary) in the user guide):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{a sample acronym}

\begin{document}

\gls{abc}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={Abbreviations}]
\end{document}
```

Second option (see [Changing the Fixed Names](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:fixednames) in the user guide):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{a sample acronym}

\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{Abbreviations}

\begin{document}

\gls{abc}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Both the above will produce:

[image: Image of resulting document]

If you do decide to use `babel` (or if someone else happens on this question who wants a more general answer) either use option 1 above or:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[acronym,translate=babel]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{a sample acronym}

\addto\captionsbritish
{%
  \renewcommand*{\acronymname}{Abbreviations}
}

\begin{document}

\gls{abc}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

In this specific case (use "Abbreviations" rather than "Acronyms") another possibility is to use the extension package [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nomain,% don't create 'main' glossary
 abbreviations% create 'abbreviations' glossary
]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{short}

\newabbreviation{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}
\newacronym{nato}{NATO}{North Atlantic Treaty Organization}

\begin{document}

\gls{html} and \gls{nato}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: hypertext markup language (HTML) and NATO. Abbreviations HTML hypertext markup language 1 NATO North Atlantic Treaty Organization 1]